# Database context life time vs Realtime communications

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**According to Microsoft**

> the database context lifetime should be very short and any instantiated
> objects should be disabled and removed from the ram as soon as they are no longer needed.

While I was developing an POS **WPF** application ,which based on *caliburn.Micro* framework and IOC container was implemented, I separated the project as following:

- the entities classes & the context were putted in separated **Class
  Library** project.
- I implemented the repository and unit of work
  design patterns in the main wpf project and i injected the context in
  the unit of work class constructor.
- I registered the context and the
  unit of work into the ioc container **"Autofac Container"** with
  **InstancePerDependency** life time for both of them which means a new instance will be created whenever an object of each on of them is

  requested.
- Finally ,i injected the unit of work interface into the **ViewModel** classes so i can load the proper entities for each VM in its constructor.

**and the problems came here.**

When I was trying to add a Product' Category and then I navigate to the Products VM to add a new product under this category ,but the VM didn't recognize that I had added new category.

when I traced the code I found that it happens with any VM. The VMs weren't feeling the changes except when I restart the program. I tried to fix it in many ways but no thing worked with me ,wo i decided to change the lifetime of the context to be **"SingleInstance"** which means one instance of the context will be created for whole the project.

I know it's a bad practice but there weren't any other choices.

**The Questions are:**

- why did it happen?
- what was the proper solution at this situation ?
- does it also happen in the other workloads like mvc ,web apis or the Scoped lifetime handles it in the dot net core services container ?
- was my separation structure correct and does it work fine for other projects or not?

**Update:**
This is my product entity:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ProductBarcodes = new HashSet<ProductBarcode>();
        InventoriesProducts = new HashSet<InventoriesProducts>();
        ProductUnits = new HashSet<ProductUnits>();
        ProductsVariants = new HashSet<ProductsVariants>();
    }
    [Key]
    public string Productkey { get; set; }
    [Required,MaxLength(150), MinLength(3)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public decimal? SalesPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
    public bool CanBeSold { get; set; }
    public bool CanBePurchased { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProductBarcode.Product))]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductBarcode> ProductBarcodes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InventoriesProducts> InventoriesProducts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductUnits> ProductUnits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductsVariants> ProductsVariants { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Category entity :

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(150), MinLength(3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This project supports english and arabic languages so,i implemented the results messages as following:

- I added the ITransactionResult generic interface that describe how any transaction result should be and it's generic to give me the ability to pass the entity type that i'm going to give transaction results about.
- The interface has a **UserMessageResource** property of type **Type** this property usually was setted to **Properties.Resources** to search for a registered resource which contains the arabic or english message that will be displayed after the transaction.
- Then i added two classes to implement this interface to describe two cases , when the Transaction ends successfully which was presented in SucessTransaction class and other wises were presented in FailedTransaction class.

**ITransactionResult :**

```
 public interface ITransactionResult<T> where T : class
{
    Exception ExceptionHappend { get; }
    string UserMessage { get; }
    string SourceType { get; }
    bool Success { get; }
    Type UserMessageResource { get; }
    string UserMessageName { get; }
    string[] Notes { get; }
}
```

**SucessTransaction:**

```
public class SuccessTransaction<T> : ITransactionResult<T> where T : class
{
    public SuccessTransaction(string message,params string[] notes)
    {
        Success = true;
        ExceptionHappend = null;
        Notes = notes;
        UserMessage = message;
    }
    public SuccessTransaction(Type UserMessageResource,string UserMessageName, params string[] notes):this(string.Empty,notes)
    {
        this.UserMessageResource = UserMessageResource;
        this.UserMessageName = UserMessageName;
        UserMessage = UserMessageResource.GetProperty(UserMessageName).GetValue(UserMessageResource).ToString();
    }
    public Exception ExceptionHappend { get; }
    public string UserMessage { get; }
    public bool Success {get;}
    public string SourceType { get => nameof(T); }
    public Type UserMessageResource { get; }
    public string UserMessageName { get; }
    public string[] Notes { get; }
}
```

**FailedTransaction :**

```
public class FailedTransaction<T> : ITransactionResult<T> where T : class
{
    public FailedTransaction(string message,Exception exception,params string[] notes)
    {
        Success = false;
        UserMessage = message;
        ExceptionHappend = exception;
        Notes = notes;
    }
    public FailedTransaction(Type UserMessageResource, string UserMessageName,Exception exception, params string[] notes)
        :this(string.Empty,exception,notes)
    {
        this.UserMessageResource = UserMessageResource;
        this.UserMessageName = UserMessageName;
        UserMessage = UserMessageResource.GetProperty(UserMessageName).GetValue(UserMessageResource).ToString();
    }
    public Exception ExceptionHappend { get; }
    public string UserMessage { get; }
    public bool Success { get; }
    public string SourceType { get => nameof(T); }
    public Type UserMessageResource { get; }
    public string UserMessageName { get; }
    public string[] Notes { get; }
}
```

**My Product repo :**

```
public class ProductRepo : IProductRepo
{
    private DbContext dbContext;
    public Type DisplayResourceType { get; set; }
    public ProductRepo(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public Product Add(Product entity, out ITransactionResult<Product> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = dbContext.Add(entity);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "Adding_S");
            return res.Entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "Adding_F", ex);
            return entity;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> AddRange(IEnumerable<Product> entites, out ITransactionResult<Product> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.AddRange(entites);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "AddingRang_S");
            return entites;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "AddingRange_F", ex);
            return entites;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll() => GetAllAsQueryable().ToList();

    public IQueryable<Product> GetAllAsQueryable() => dbContext.Set<Product>();

    public Product GetById(string id) => dbContext.Find<Product>(id);

    public bool IsExist(string id, out Product entity)
    {
        entity = GetById(id);
        return entity != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void Remove(Product entity, out ITransactionResult<Product> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = dbContext.Remove(entity);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "Removing_S");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "Removing_F", ex);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<Product> entities, out ITransactionResult<Product> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.AddRange(entities);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "RemovingRange_S");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "RemovingRange_F", ex);
        }
    }

    public Product Update(Product entity, out ITransactionResult<Product> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = dbContext.Update(entity);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "Updating_S");
            return res.Entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "Updating_F", ex);
            return entity;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> UpdateRange(IEnumerable<Product> entities, out ITransactionResult<Product> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.UpdateRange(entities);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "UpdatingRange_S");
            return entities;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<Product>(DisplayResourceType, "UpdatingRange_F", ex);
            return entities;
        }
    }
}
```

**Category repo :**

```
public class CategoryRepo : ICategoryRepo
{
    private DbContext dbContext;

    public Type DisplayResourceType { get; set; }

    public CategoryRepo(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> GetAll() => GetAllAsQueryable().ToList();

    public IQueryable<ProductCategory> GetAllAsQueryable() => dbContext.Set<ProductCategory>();

    public ProductCategory GetById(long id) => dbContext.Find<ProductCategory>(id);

    public ProductCategory Add(ProductCategory entity, out ITransactionResult<ProductCategory> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = dbContext.Add(entity);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "Adding_S");
            return res.Entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "Adding_F", ex);
            return entity;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> AddRange(IEnumerable<ProductCategory> entites, out ITransactionResult<ProductCategory> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.AddRange(entites);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "AddingRang_S");
            return entites;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "AddingRange_F", ex);
            return entites;
        }
    }

    public ProductCategory Update(ProductCategory entity, out ITransactionResult<ProductCategory> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = dbContext.Update(entity);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "Updating_S");
            return res.Entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "Updating_F", ex);
            return entity;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> UpdateRange(IEnumerable<ProductCategory> entities, out ITransactionResult<ProductCategory> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.UpdateRange(entities);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "UpdatingRange_S");
            return entities;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "UpdatingRange_F", ex);
            return entities;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(ProductCategory entity, out ITransactionResult<ProductCategory> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = dbContext.Remove(entity);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "Removing_S");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "Removing_F", ex);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<ProductCategory> entities, out ITransactionResult<ProductCategory> transactionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.AddRange(entities);
            transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "RemovingRange_S");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transactionResult = new FailedTransaction<ProductCategory>(DisplayResourceType, "RemovingRange_F", ex);
        }
    }

    public bool IsExist(long id, out ProductCategory entity)
    {
        entity = GetById(id);
        return entity != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to share some code so we can better understand what your application is doing and so others can replicate the problem you describe.

Comment: DbContext is a unit of work and the lifetime of its instance should be per transaction.

Comment: i'm talking in general bro and i think i have described what happened long-windedly

Comment: Would help to see the code that enabled you to do this: *When I was trying to add a Product' Category and then I navigate to the Products VM to add a new product under this category ,but the VM didn't recognize that I had added new category.*

Comment: In general once you have a poco you need to add (like a category to a product) you' have to look up the product (again) and add the category using a single dbcontext instance. Or attach disconnected entities like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)

Comment: thanks for your time and helping . i've added the requested code if u don't mind please review it and ask if any further code is needed